# Fanny's Occurences

Tags: python

Fanny is given a string along with the string which contains single character x. She has to remove the character x from the given string. Help her write a function to remove all occurrences of x character from the given string.
Input Specification:

Input 1: input string s

Input 2: String containing any character x

Output Specification:

String without the occurrence of character x

Example 1:

Input:

welcome to mettl

l

Output:

wecome to mett

Explanation: As I is the character which is required to be removed, therefore all the occurrences of I are removed, keeping all other characters.

Example 2:

input1: I out of Rings

Input2: o

Output: I ut f Rings

**MY solution:**

```
def extractSecretMessage(Str, Sub): 
    Str= Str.replace(Sub, " ")     
    return Str.strip() 
Str = input("")
Sub = input("")
print(extractSecretMessage(Str, Sub))
```

ERROR:
Input (stdin)

Tamilarasan guna
a
Your Output (stdout)

T mil r s n gun
Expected Output

Tmilrsn gun
Compiler Message

Nice try, But you did not pass the test case!

Comment: But in what is the question?

Comment: Fanny is given a string along with the string which contains single character x. She has to remove the character x from the given string. Help her write a function to remove all occurrences of x character from the given string. Input Specification:

Input 1: input string s

Input 2: String containing any character x

Output Specification:

String without the occurrence of character x

Example 1:

Input:

welcome to mettl

l

Output:

wecome to mett

Comment: No, what is **your** question. StackOverflow is not a place for "make a task for me".

Comment: First two test cases is passed but the 3rd one showing error. Input (stdin):

*Tamilarasan guna a* Your Output (stdout)

*T mil r s n gun* Expected Output

*Tmilrsn gun*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are supposed to remove a character, you are replacing it with a space, when you should be replacing it with an empty string.

Another potential problem (although not exposed in these examples) is that you are calling `strip()` (which will remove leading and trailing whitespace) when the specification does not say that you are meant to do this.  (In some cases, it could mask the previous bug, if the space that you wrongly added was at the start or end of the string.)

Where you have:

```
    Str= Str.replace(Sub, " ")     
    return Str.strip()
```

you should use:

```
    Str= Str.replace(Sub, "")     
    return Str
```

or simply:

```
    return Str.replace(Sub, "")
```